# Flex-Wrap Inside Flex-Grow

Tags: css, flexbox, flex-grow

This question is similar to [Flex box with wrap inside another Flex box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000703/flex-box-with-wrap-inside-another-flex-box), but no solution was found.

Here's the structure:

```
<div> // flex wrapper
    <div></div> // flex: 1 1 80%;
    <div></div> // flex: 1 1 20%;
</div>
```

The wrapper's second child also contains children, and this child also has `flex-wrap: wrap;` applied to it. The problem is that it isn't expanding as you'd expect given `flex: 1 1 20%;` when more children are added than will fit in its current width.

You can see this behavior in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/narthur/6fd3o4dp/3/) by clicking the "More" button until the second child's children overflows. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Problem Screenshot]

How can the second child be made to continue expanding when more grandchildren are added?